# Adding array to a list how to stop it being the last iteration data?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a list of an array of 2 items. The problem I have is the final iteration in my loop sets all the list's arrays to the same (my guess is due to a reference?). I was wondering how I can prevent this from happening.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
PathTiles[] links = new PathTiles[2];
int j;
for(int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
{
   if(i+1 < path.Count)
   {
    links[0]    = path[i];
    links[1]    = path[i];

    for(j = i+1; j < path.Count; j++)
    {
       if(path[j].x == links[1].x && Mathf.Abs(path[j].y-links[1].y) == 1)
       {
          links[1] = path[j];
          i = j;
       }
       else 
       {    
        break;
       }
    }
    validPath.Add(links);
    for(int k = 0; k < validPath.Count;k++)
    {
       Debug.Log(validPath[k].x+", "+validPath[k].y);
    }
    Debug.Log("=====");
  }
}
```

So the console shows this:

```
0, 0 
=====
1, 1   <-- why did this become 1, 1 and not stay as 0, 0
1, 1
=====
```

Does any one know how I can retain the first data value and not have it overwritten? I am currently under the impression it is because it stores a reference and so I changed the values, but I don't know how to stop it doing that.

Comment: Where are `validPath` and `path` defined? and why do you initialize `j` outside of the first `for` loop?

Comment: Does it matter where they are defined? This is just a snippet of code from a large script of which is causing the behavior i don't wish to have occur. 
As for why i set `j` outside, mainly because otherwise im initialization j multiple times for each i iteration, micro optimization, not really important for the question though but it's something I've done ever since i started learning C# mainly a habit nowadays.

Comment: It's not clear what the values of `path[]` are or how many elements there are in it. Also, you don't seem to close the `if` statement's braces. Is there a closing brace missing?

Comment: putting `j` in the for loop will cause basically no performance change and will be a bit tidier too!

Comment: I am not following why it needs to be known how many path elements there are or the content of path for the question i am asking... the question is about the over-writing of `validPath`'s first index. Also the if statement shows path contains an x and y data set...

Comment: This is just how reference types work. You have the one instance of the array, and you add the same instance repeatedly to the list. The marked duplicate is just one of the oldest of _many_ questions that are basically the same: "why do all of the elements in my collection have the same value?" The fix is always the same: make sure you are creating a _new_ instance of the reference type value for each element you add to your collection.

Comment: See also many of the hits here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+list+same+value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `PathTiles[] links = new PathTiles[2];` within the 1st for loop statement. As you said this is a problem of references. As you were addiing the same modified links to the list. the 1st data value is overwritten.

```
int j;
for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
{
    PathTiles[] links = new PathTiles[2]; //<-- here
    if (i + 1 < path.Count)
    {

         links[0] = path[i];
         links[1] = path[i];
         ...
```